# How to Kill Excel object in Windows Task Manager using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am using Excel object in Javascript and open and close the excel file with javascript.

Here when i close the excel object and set to null for the Excel object.

It won't remove excel object in windows task manager. Once i refresh my page then only it is removed.

Below my code to be used

```
ExcelObject.ActiveWorkBook.Close();
ExcelObject.Application.Quit();
ExcelObject = null;
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code... it forcefully terminate the process that was running in taskmanager...

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function Sam()
{
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var oExec = WshShell.Exec("taskkill /F /IM EXCEL.exe"); //here i terminate the Excel...
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="Button" Value="Kill" onclick="Sam();"/>
</body>
</html>
```